# JAVA Sending Email via Outlook with SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I used Java 1.6 in x86 to send emails via opening Outlook and send email, all commands with SWT. [source](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMicrosoftIntegration/article.html) 
Everithing works really fine, but recently my job decide to change the operation system to x64 and the version of Outlook (2010 to 2016), but for some reasons, the Java decide to keep the 1.6 
With all of this my code stop to work. Even, when i try to update SWT (1.5 to 1.8) it sends me the message: 
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

So after of research i found the next things:

  If you update the version of SWT, in x86, everithing stop to working for the error that i said before

  Even, if you keep the version of SWT (1.5) the mail doesnt open in x64

**The questions are**

There's a way to update the email code to works in x64?

There's a way to update the library from 1.5 to 1.8 and works in x64 (even un x86)?

 
And as i said it before, i cant update the java version (some weird security reasons bigger than me)

Comment: 'Unsupported major.minor version 52.0' means the code was compiled with Java 8 and  **must** also be run with Java 8.

Comment: Ok, but the previous version of swt is incompatible with x64?

Answer (score 0):

After a weeks of research i got a lot of conclucions.

The real question is "Can i upgrade the libraries without update the Java version?"

The awser is yes and no, depends most of the libraries.

Java 1.6 only supports this versions of libraries:

- SWT 4.5
- POI 3.16 --Lastest Version
- SQLJDBC 4.0

If yout try to use different libraries, the project never compiles.

Other thing, the function to open a new email in Outlook i cant reach the awser. Try to switch between OS (x86 and x64) and differents types of java 1.6 (x86 and x64) and never works in x64.

If anyone out there have a awser to create a new email with Outlook in x64 system (Windows 8 and 10) feel free to add another awser.